# Check 32 and 64 bit support individually on Termux

Tags: shell, google-pixel, termux

With Google Pixel 7 lineup ditching 32 bit support, I think it is now necessary to check for 32 and 64 bit support individually.

From what I interpret, the Google Pixel 7 series will not be able to run 32 bit (ARM) executables. It breaks my script which downloads a 32 bit executable.

If phone supports 32 bit, download the 32 bit executable. Otherwise, download the 64 bit one.

I know it is strange to download a 32 bit executable on a 64 bit device supporting 32 bit. But please, ignore it.

I think we can use `getprop` but I don't know how.

Anyway, please help.

Comment: Does anyone have a Google Pixel 7? Please run `lscpu` and help me see `CPU op modes` line.